# Trigger checkbutton hover event from another widget

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm3

I made a custom Right-to-Left check button widget using a `Gtk::CheckButton` without the label and a `Gtk::Label` inside `Gtk::EventBox`.

The reason I went this way instead of simply calling `set_direction(Gtk::TEXT_DIR_RTL)` is that I want to manually specify the alignment for these widgets.

I've figured out activating/deactivating checkbutton state when the label's clicked but I'm having trouble triggering the hover event from label to checkbutton. The default `Gtk::CheckButton` behavior triggers the hover effect on the clickable square button to indicate it's being activated when text is hovered too. How do I achieve that same behavior on my custom right-to-left checkbutton widget?

Below is the minimal reproducible code for testing:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>

using Gtk::Application;
using Gtk::Button;
using Gtk::CheckButton;
using Gtk::EventBox;
using Gtk::Grid;
using Gtk::Label;
using Gtk::Window;

class MyWindow : public Window {
    Button      button;
    CheckButton checkbutton;
    EventBox    eventbox;
    Grid        grid;
    Label       label;

    bool on_label_clicked(GdkEventButton *);
    void arrange_content_layout();
    
public:
    MyWindow();
};

bool MyWindow::on_label_clicked(GdkEventButton *event)
{
    if (event->button == 1 && event->type == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS) {
        checkbutton.set_active(!checkbutton.get_active());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void MyWindow::arrange_content_layout()
{
    checkbutton.set_margin_start(6);
    
    button.set_margin_top(24);
    grid.child_property_width(button) = 2;
    
    grid.set_margin_top(24);
    grid.set_margin_start(24);
    grid.set_margin_end(24);
    grid.set_margin_bottom(24);
}

MyWindow::MyWindow()
    : button("Click to steal focus")
    , label ("Our custom RTL label")
{
    eventbox.add(label);
    eventbox.signal_button_press_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(
            *this, &MyWindow::on_label_clicked));
    
    grid.add(eventbox);
    grid.add(checkbutton);
    grid.attach(button, 0, 1);
    
    add(grid);
    
    arrange_content_layout();
    set_default_size(120, 60);
    
    show_all();
}

int main()
{
    auto app = Application::create("domain.reverse.sample.rtl-checkbutton");
    
    MyWindow window;
    
    return app->run(window);
}
```

Comment: What alignment do you want to manually specify? It's probably better done using CSS. I don't think `GtkWidget:margin*` are advised, and the similar `GtkContainer:border-width` was outright removed in GTK4 (as was `GtkContainer`, but still...)

Comment: Center Align the `Gtk::CheckButton` with other toggle buttons above in one column and end align the label with the remaining widgets in another column. That way all toggle buttons appear aligned in one column and so does previous columns too. The default `Gtk::CheckButton` with label specified appears too close to each other and I don't like to eyeball with spaces to make them aligned with the surrounding widgets.

Comment: @underscore_d `set_valign` and `set_halign`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [`set_state_flags()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a382fb9fd8f1fd35bf30a4eaf0d087890) and trick the visual output of your Right-to-Left checkbutton when the label is being hovered.

First, you need to enable these two masks for `eventbox` to capture *enter* and *leave* event:

- **Gdk::ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK**
- **Gdk::LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK**

```cpp
eventbox.add_events(Gdk::ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK | Gdk::LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK);
```

And connect `eventbox` signals

```cpp
class MyWindow : public Window {
    ...
    bool on_label_entered(GdkEventCrossing *);
    bool on_label_exited(GdkEventCrossing *);
    ...
}

MyWindow::MyWindow()
    ...
{
    ...
    eventbox.signal_enter_notify_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(
            *this, &MyWindow::on_label_entered));
    eventbox.signal_leave_notify_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(
            *this, &MyWindow::on_label_exited));
    ...
```

And finally, use `Gtk::STATE_FLAG_PRELIGHT` to do the UI trick

```cpp
// Enter event
bool MyWindow::on_label_entered(GdkEventCrossing *event)
{
    if (event->mode != GDK_CROSSING_NORMAL) return false;

    checkbutton.set_state_flags(checkbutton.get_state_flags() | Gtk::STATE_FLAG_PRELIGHT);

    return true;
}

// Leave event
bool MyWindow::on_label_exited(GdkEventCrossing *event)
{
    if (event->mode != GDK_CROSSING_NORMAL) return false;

    checkbutton.unset_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_PRELIGHT);

    return true;
}
```